# how to define relative path in java

Tags: java, relative-path

I have a java project that is being deployed on server. My java project reads from a local file. I need to give the function the relative path so that my code can have access to the file. The file is also being deployed to the server. I have struggle defining the relative path. I have defined my relative path as below.

here is the error I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: ....\WebContent\resources\dataSource\ppmsOrigin.XLSX (The system cannot find the path specified)

I also used export to .war file and then deployed it to the server

```
ArrayDataModel<Record> records = this.processDataSources("..\\..\\WebContent\\resources\\dataSource\\ppmsOrigin.XLSX", "..\\WebContent\\resources\\dataSource\\product_database-reverse-column.xlsx", "ppms_ppms","product_db",5, 4 ,1,1 );
```

here is how the hierarchy is in my project 
[image]

Comment: How is this being deployed?  How are you packaging?  What error are you getting?

Comment: I use export as .war file and then deployed it in the server. But I tested it on my local and this relative path is not working. my code can't find the local file give this relative path.

Comment: I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\..\WebContent\resources\dataSource\ppmsOrigin.XLSX (The system cannot find the path specified) error

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?  Maybe the working directory is not what you think it is.  I think by default it would be the project directory, not the directory with your source code.

Comment: @puhlen, I am not sure if my path is correct, a function inside of ProcessFileUtility.java wants to read a local file inside of dataSource folder. I though relative path with only care about the path between 2 files rather than where the working directory is.

Comment: @user1836957 relative paths are always based on the working directory

Comment: @puhlen, How can I give a path to a function to find my file once the whole project is deployed on the server since my working directory is different there.